# Поисковая оптимизация: минимизация потерь при дублировании содержимого

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы, поисковая-оптимизация

Известно (например, из доументации Google), что первое, на что смотрит поисковик - это уникальность контента, и если информация есть на других сайтах, сайт может быть серьёзно занижен.

Возникла такая ситуация, что я захотел, чтобы одна и та же статья была сразу на двух моих сайтах. Она нужна **на обоих** сайтах, а перенаправлять пользователей на другой сайт - тоже нежелательно, т. к. они уже могут не вернуться на первый.

Вопрос: как минимизировать потери траффика из-за дублирования содержимого?

- Вероятно, оба сайта будут брать эту статью из одной и той же БД, но при этом иметь и свои собственные БД.
- Разумеется, что помимо этой статьи оба сайта будут иметь и собственное уникальное содержание.
- Не знаю, повлияет ли это на что-то, но вероятно оба сайта будут на одном и том же хостинге.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете применять элемент [blockquote](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_blockquote.asp) и создать разметку структурированными данными для ссылки как [copyrightHolder](https://schema.org/copyrightHolder) (для Организации, Персоны, Креативной работы, и так далее).